# How to get around cref reference format undefined when using * variant of newtheorem

Tags: cleveref, amsthm, newtheorem

I would like to know a way to use newtheorem* and use cref on the labelled theorem. cleveref doesn't seem to work nicely with this * variant.

Example resulting in "cref reference format for label type `' undefined":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem {hey}{Sandwich}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem*{hi}{Creek}

\begin{document}
\begin{hey}\label{sand}
aa
\end{hey}

\begin{hi}\label{dirt}
bb
\end{hi}

\cref{sand} % Sandwich 1

\cref{dirt} % warning and results in ??; want: Creek

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newtheorem*` defines a numberless theorem and `\label` in the `hi` environment essentially points to a random reference. What do you expect `\cref{dirt}` to output?

Comment: @egreg I am expecting `\cref{dirt}` to output "Creek", just as `\cref{sand}` outputs "Sandwich 1", but without the numbering.

Comment: If you use “Creek” more than once, what would be the usefulness of this? If it is a one-instance statement, you don't need `\cref`, do you?

Comment: @egreg Well other than things like hyperref and keeping to a format for all theorems, numbered or not, I'm also doing it for convenience when I need to tweak names and when the name is awfully long and I refer to it often.

Comment: @egreg If there are complete alternatives, I would love to know. I'm pretty new to latex, having created 3 documents in total with it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `\newtheorem*` doesn't allocate a counter, using `\cref` will not work. If you just want to abbreviate a long name, use a macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem {hey}{Sandwich}
\newcommand{\CR}{Creek}
\newtheorem*{hi}{\CR}

\begin{document}
\begin{hey}\label{sand}
aa
\end{hey}

\begin{hi}
bb
\end{hi}

\cref{sand} % Sandwich 1

\CR % Creek

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand you might have several named theorems, and using `cleveref` will help.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem {hey}{Sandwich}

\newtheoremstyle{named}
  {\topsep}     % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}     % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont} % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries}   % HEADFONT
  {.}           % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{named}
\newtheorem{namedinner}{\protect\thenamedinner}
\newenvironment{named}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\thenamedinner}{#1}\namedinner}
 {\endnamedinner}
\crefformat{namedinner}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{hey}\label{sand}
aa
\end{hey}

\begin{named}{Creek}\label{dirt}
bb
\end{named}

\begin{named}{River}\label{rain}
cc
\end{named}

\cref{sand} % Sandwich 1

\cref{dirt} % Creek

\cref{rain} % River

\end{document}
```

[image]